# Sorting a one dimensional array of dates

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sort an array containing only date values.

I want the latest date in the upper bound of the array:

```vb
Function vba_sort_array_a_to_z(ByRef myArray)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Temp As String
    
    'sorting array from A to Z
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(myArray)
            If UCase(myArray(i)) > UCase(myArray(j)) Then
                Temp = myArray(j)
                myArray(j) = myArray(i)
                myArray(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

Dummy array before sorting:
[image]

Expecting "12.04.2022" to be sorted to the upper bound of the array:

```vb
Sub sortThisArray()
    Dim vDate() As Date: ReDim vDate(0 To 2)
    vDate(0) = "25.03.2022"
    vDate(1) = "12.04.2022"
    vDate(2) = "14.02.2022"
    Call vba_sort_array_a_to_z(vDate)
    Stop
End Sub
```

After sorting:
[image]

I assume the sort algorithm is taking the first indicators into account, which would be the day of the date in this case. So "12", "14" and "25".

The only idea I had is to manipulate the whole array containing the dates by creating a temp array (as long) and insert the date values in the format YYYYMMDD to the temp array, then sorting that array and transferring the values back to another array and reformat it again in the desired target date format. This seems inefficient.

Result of the sorted temp array would look like this:
[image]

Is there another way to achieve this?

If this is the only solution, I am thinking of creating a new function out of it, which handles only the sorting of dates.

Comment: I am not sure I get your point right, but as you can see in the variable observing window that the values are formatted as "Date". So Excel knows those are date values.

Comment: I did not look to the window... Then, only eliminate `UCase`...

Comment: you were right about the UCase thing. Haven't looked at the function I found in detail. Very interesting thing regarding the UCase thing! Appreciate your help.

Comment: DOn't write your own sort code.  Pick one from here https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-%28sort-array-sorting-arrays%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you convert the dates into strings before comparing them in your sort routine. This routine was probably written to sort strings and is using the function `UCase` that converts a string into uppercases (so that string are sorted case-independently).
So what happens in the background is that the date (which is internally a number) is converted into a string (a series of bytes) and these strings are used when you compare the values. And the *string* `25.03.2022` is larger than the *string* `12.04.2022` (because the character `2` is larger than the character `1`).

Quick fix would be to remove the `Ucase`-function:

```
If myArray(i) > myArray(j) Then
```

However, if you want to use the sorting routine also for strings, you could do something like

```
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(myArray)
        Dim isLarger As Boolean
        If VarType(myArray(i)) = vbString Then
            isLarger = UCase(myArray(i)) > UCase(myArray(j))
        Else
            isLarger = myArray(i) > myArray(j)
        End If
        
        If isLarger Then
            Temp = myArray(j)
            myArray(j) = myArray(i)
            myArray(i) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: exactly, @FaneDuru also commented on this topic to my question. Thank you.